# Delete all position in DbContext from BindingSource.List using Entity (EF6)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6, entity

I have DbContext with table named:`base.books`

and BindingSource from LINQ query with records which I want to delete using `RemoveRange`.

```
Dim query = From books
        In base.books
        Where //some conditions
        Select books.id, books.name,
Dim BooksSource As New BindingSource
BooksSource.DataSource = query.ToList
DataGridView_Books.DataSource = BooksSource.DataSource
```

After some changes in `DataGridView_Books` I want delete all positions from `DataGridView_Books` in `base.books`.

I imagine it that way:

```
listA=BooksSource.DataSource.List
''listB=convert(listA)    
base.books.RemoveRange(listB)
base.books.SaveChanges()
```

but I do not know how to replace `convert` (I mean: 'System.Collections.IList' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable')

Thanks.

Comment: This line is wrong: `DataGridView_Books.DataSource = BooksSource.DataSource`. that should be this: `DataGridView_Books.DataSource = BooksSource`. Otherwise, the `BindingSource` is pointless.

Comment: There's no conversion to be done. The `IList` interface inherits the `IEnumerable` interface so, if you have an `IList`, you already have an `IEnumerable`.